# MongoDB Query for NON NULL fields

Tags: jquery, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on a web scraping assignment and need to only show articles scraped that have a title, link, AND summary.

If any of these are null I don't want to find them. This is my JS code:

```
results.link = $(element).find("a").attr("href");
results.title = $(element).find("a").text().trim();
results.summary = $(element).find("p.summary").text().trim();
```

I've tried variations of exists and type through mongo documentation but can't seem to pull the values I need. Any help is appreciated.

```
// Route for getting all Articles from the db
app.get("/articles", function (req, res) {
  // Grab every document in the Articles collection that has a distinct title
  db.Article.distinct("results.title")
    .then(function (dbArticle) {
      // If we were able to successfully find Articles, send them back to the client
      res.json(dbArticle);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      // If an error occurred, send it to the client
      res.json(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: You have added tag Mongodb and mongodb-query but you are showing jquery code. What do you mean by "to do this correctly"

Comment: @Ashish451 I edited the question to hopefully be more clear. I am storing data using mongo, and need to only display articles with non null values in all three required fields (title, link, summary)

Comment: So you want to se results.link only when a -> href is not null ?

Comment: @Ashish451 yep, I want to exclude any articles that have an empty title/link/summary and only show those that have all three fields filled

Answer (score 0):

you can check for null values

```
// return true if value is null else false
function isNullOrEmpty(data){
    if(data == null || data == "" || data.trim().length == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var link = $(element).find("a").attr("href");
var title = $(element).find("a").text().trim();
var summary = $(element).find("p.summary").text().trim();

// assign value only if all of them has some value
if( !isNullOrEmpty(link) &&  !isNullOrEmpty(title) && !isNullOrEmpty(summary)){

    results.link = link;
    results.title = title;
    results.summary = summary
}
```